# Why is my recyclerview not showing on my tab layout fragment?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

So I'm trying to display the following and followers recyclerview from GitHub's API. So there are two fragments for 2 tablayouts for followers and following.

This is the code for my FollowingFragment

```
 class FollowingFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentFollowingBinding
    private var list = ArrayList<Users>()

    companion object {
        private val ARG_USERNAME = "extra_username"

        fun newInstance(username:String):Fragment{
            var fragment = FollowingFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString(ARG_USERNAME,username)
            fragment.arguments = bundle
            return fragment
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val username = arguments?.getString(ARG_USERNAME)
        setListUser(username)
        binding.rvFollowing.setHasFixedSize(true)
        showRecyclerList()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentFollowingBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        val view: View = binding.root
        return view
    }

    private fun showRecyclerList() {
        binding.rvFollowing.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        val listUserAdapter = FollowingAdapter(list)
        binding.rvFollowing.adapter = listUserAdapter
    }

    private fun setListUser(username: String?) {
        val listItems = ArrayList<Users>()
        val token = "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"
        val url = "https://api.github.com/users/$username/following"

        val client = AsyncHttpClient()
        client.addHeader("Authorization","token $token")
        client.addHeader("User-Agent","request")
        client.get(url,object: AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
            override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>, responseBody: ByteArray) {
                //parsingjson
                try {
                    val result = String(responseBody)
                    val items = JSONArray(result)

                    for (i in 0 until items.length()){
                        val UserClass = Users()
                        val user = items.getJSONObject(i)
                        val username = user.getString("login")
                        val avatar = user.getString("avatar_url")
                        UserClass.login = username
                        UserClass.avatar = avatar
                        listItems.add(UserClass)
                        Log.d("TAG","$username $avatar")
                    }
                    list = listItems
                } catch (e: Exception){
                    Log.d("Exception",e.message.toString())
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>, responseBody: ByteArray, error: Throwable) {
                Log.d("onFailure",error.message.toString())
            }

        })
    }
}
```

This is the code for my following recyclerview adapter:

```
    class FollowingAdapter(private val listFollowing: ArrayList<Users>): RecyclerView.Adapter<FollowingAdapter.UserViewHolder>() {
    class UserViewHolder(private val binding:ItemRowDeveloperProfilesBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(user:Users){
            with(binding){
                Glide.with(itemView.context)
                        .load(user.avatar)
                        .apply(RequestOptions().override(400,400))
                        .into(imgProfilePictureSearch)
                usernameSearch.text = user.login
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemRowDeveloperProfilesBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return UserViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(listFollowing[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listFollowing.size
    }


}
```

The full code can be seen on my github repository https://github.com/briancatraguna/GitHubClone. I'm really not sure what I did wrong here? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the listItems before getting the list from the api calls ( this is true for your search users page as well).

Move your showRecyclerView() to the onSuccess callback of the AsyncHttpClient get Call ..